# CSV file data to Excel (Remove csv file after workbook save not working)

Tags: python, pandas, permissions, operating-system

I'm having trouble removing the csv file after the data is integrated into the workbook. I'm getting a message

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process!
```

and I tried closing the file before I am applying the os.remove syntax to my code. I am curretly stuck in what I should do. I've tried a few methods, but the end statement keeps popping up.

```
# importing pandas
#importing os
import pandas as pd
import os


csv_1 = open('SearchResults.csv', 'r')

csv_2 = open('SearchResults (1).csv', 'r')

csv_3 = open('SearchResults (2).csv', 'r')
  
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DB_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
# merging three csv files
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,[csv_1,csv_2,csv_3]), ignore_index=True)

#Exports csv files to excel sheet on DB_1.xlsx
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheetname')

csv_1.close()
csv_2.close()
csv_3.close()

writer.save()

try:
    os.remove('SearchResults.csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults.csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))
    

try:
    os.remove('SearchResults (1).csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults (1).csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))
    
try:
    os.remove('SearchResults (2).csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults (2).csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))
```

#Results:

```
Error: SearchResults.csv - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process!
Error: SearchResults (1).csv - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process!
Error: SearchResults (2).csv - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process!
```

Comment: Excel likes to lock files it is using. Perhaps try writing, saving and closing your excel writer before attempting to close your csv files.

Comment: maybe files *.csv are opened in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

Using pathlib.glob to find all files, concatenate the csv files with a generator to excel. Finally delete csv files.

```
import contextlib
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


def concatenate_csvs(path: str) -> None:
    pd.concat(
        (pd.read_csv(x) for x in Path(f"{path}/").glob("SearchResults*.csv")), ignore_index=True
    ).to_excel(f"{path}/DB_1.xlsx", index=False, sheet_name="sheetname")

    with contextlib.suppress(PermissionError):
        [Path(x).unlink() for x in Path(f"{path}/").glob("SearchResults*.csv")]


concatenate_csvs("/path/to/files")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do line by line operations on your three `.csv` files (and it doesn't seem to be the case here), there is no need to use python's *built-in* funciton [`open`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#open) with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

csv_1 = 'SearchResults.csv'
csv_2 = 'SearchResults (1).csv'
csv_3 = 'SearchResults (2).csv'
  
# merging three csv files
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,[csv_1,csv_2,csv_3]), ignore_index=True)
    
with pd.ExcelWriter('DB_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer :
    #Exports csv files to excel sheet on DB_1.xlsx
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheetname')

try:
    os.remove('SearchResults.csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults.csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))

try:
    os.remove('SearchResults (1).csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults (1).csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))
    
try:
    os.remove('SearchResults (2).csv')
    print("The file: {} is deleted!".format('SearchResults (2).csv'))
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {} - {}!".format(e.filename, e.strerror))
```